# Extended Partition option grayed out on GPT disk in GParted

Tags: 18.04, partitioning

I'm trying to create a new extended partition using **GParted**. I checked using **gdisk** and found that my disk is MBR.

[image: Screenshot of gdisk output]

I've read on other posts that **Extended partition** option isn't available on GPT disk. But I've **MBR** disk stil that option isn't available.

[image: Screenshot of GParted]

Please help to figure out the reason as I desperately need to create more partitions.

Answer (score 2):

GPT does not support extended partitions.

GPT does not need extended partitions, as the limit of four primary partitions in MBR/ms-dos was removed with GPT. "*MBR also only supports up to four primary partitions—if you want more, you have to make one of your primary partitions an “extended partition” and create logical partitions inside it. This is a silly little hack and shouldn’t be necessary.*" Thanks to https://www.howtogeek.com/193669/whats-the-difference-between-gpt-and-mbr-when-partitioning-a-drive/

Answer (score 0):

With MBR alias MSDOS partition table you can have only 4 primary partitions.One of them could be an extended partition, which is a container for logical partitions, so that you can have more than 4 partitions.

You have 4 partitions already, and one of them is an extended partition. I think you can have only one extended partition.

So you should **increase the size of this extended partition to include all unallocated drive space**, Then you can create logical partitions inside it.

`gparted` is a good tool for these tasks, but you must swap off in order to remove the lock.

---

Please **backup** everything that you cannot afford to lose, because editing partitions is risky.

It is a good idea to **boot from another drive** in order to edit partitions, for example from an Ubuntu live USB drive.

Comment: Your gdisk also shows an invalid backup gpt partition table. Did you use Windows tools to convert from gpt to MBR? They leave the backup gpt partition table and then Linux tools are not sure if you have gpt or MBR? You also show sda1 as an ESP - efi system partition and gpt is normally used with UEFI boot from ESP. Ubuntu will let you use MBR with UEFI, but probably should not. You either need to fully convert to MBR by removing backup gpt  or convert back to gpt. To remove backup gpt: http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/ To convert to gpt: http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/mbr2gpt.html

Comment: Or is it only a view with `gdisk` (maybe was not written)?

Comment: It would not be written unless saved. But that is exists in a drive that is MBR usually is an issue.

Comment: Does it means that `gdisk` is only showing the disk as **MBR** but actually the disk isn't **MBR**? @sudodus

Comment: Even gdisk says it is MBR only, but also says invalid gpt which if MBR, should not be there. You can confirm with fdisk or parted. `sudo fdisk -lu` or `sudo parted -l` And they will say dos or msdos, not gpt. The only reason now, for MBR is if you are booting Windows in BIOS mode. Then MBR is required. Ubuntu can boot in BIOS or UEFI boot modes from gpt, but needs ESP partition for UEFI boot or bios_grub partition for BIOS boot for grub to correctly install. And if dual booting, you need all systems booting in same boot mode, and partitioning to match.

Comment: @ShashankShekhar, I am not sure. I based the advice on the information from gparted. But the information from gdisk shows that things might be different. Please try (but backup all valuable data first (before editing the partitions).